# How to change the color of a property in CMFCPropertyGridCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

How can I change color of a property(single property among all other properties)  in `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Do you mean the background colour? What have you tried?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle  actually I need to change  back ground color  and as well as text color of the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to derive a class from the [`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983759.aspx) class, and override the [`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnDrawProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982335.aspx) method. This allows you to change the device context to your liking prior to calling the default implementation:

```cpp
class CMFCMyPropertyGridCtrl : public CMFCPropertyGridCtrl {

public:
    virtual int OnDrawProperty( CDC * pDC, CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pProp ) const {
        // Implement check to see, if this is the property we are looking for
        // If it is, set an appropriate text color
        pDC->SetTextColor( RGB( 0xff, 0x0, 0xff ) );

        // Call the default implementation to perform rendering
        return CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnDrawProperty( pDC, pProp );
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if this approach also affects the label I left?

Comment: I am looking at colouring the background of complete row for specific property.

Answer (score 1):

[`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::SetCustomColors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class?view=msvc-170#setcustomcolors)  will do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [`SetCustomColors()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class#setcustomcolors) changes the color of *all* elements. It cannot be used to set the color of a specific item.